# Scala implicit conversion(String to a custom class and its subclass)

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

**Here's the code,**

```
trait TestBase{}

class TestA(str:String) extends TestBase

class TestB(str:String) extends TestBase

class TestC(str:String) extends TestBase

implicit def mystr2TestA(str:String):TestA = {println(str);null.asInstanceOf[TestA]}

implicit def mystr2TestB(str:String):TestB = {println(str);null.asInstanceOf[TestB]}

implicit def mystr2TestC(str:String):TestC = {println(str);null.asInstanceOf[TestC]}

val testA:TestA = "abc"

val testB:TestB = "abc"

val testC:TestC = "abc"
```

**Question is how to create the implicit conversion from `String` to `TestBase` and its subclass with more elegant and efficient code?(Maybe just one implicit function?)** [This is the Code I run in Scala REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij5w4.png)

Comment: Plus, **Class NotTest(str:String)**; **val notTest:NotTest="abc"** shall not pass compilation since NotTest is not a subclass of TestBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite this as one implicit def like this.

```
implicit def conv[A <: TestBase](str: String): A = {println(str); null.asInstanceOf[A] }
```

But depending on what you are *really* trying to, there might be a better solution than converting all `Strings` to any `TestBase`.

---

**EDIT:**
For some reason Scala doesn't seem to consider the type constraint when selecting the implicit conversion. It gets even weirder:

```
scala> implicit def bla2Test[A](str: String)(implicit ev: A <:< TestBase): A = null.asInstanceOf[A]
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
bla2Test: [A](str: String)(implicit ev: <:<[A,TestBase])A

scala> val notTest: NotTest = "str"
notTest: NotTest = null

scala> implicitly[NotTest <:< TestBase]
<console>:15: error: Cannot prove that NotTest <:< TestBase.
              implicitly[NotTest <:< TestBase]
                        ^
```

So the compiler supplies an instance of `NotTest <:< TestBase` to `bla2Test` but no instance exists.

And when you want to inspect the type `A`:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala>  implicit def bla2Test[A <: TestBase](str: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]): A = { println(tag); null.asInstanceOf[A] }
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
bla2Test: [A <: TestBase](str: String)(implicit tag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])A

scala> val notTest: NotTest = "str"
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("str")
 required: NotTest
       val notTest: NotTest = "str"
                              ^

scala> val notTest: TestBase = "str"
<console>:20: error: macro has not been expanded
       val notTest: TestBase = "str"
                               ^
```

Comment: suppose I have a **class NotTest(str:String)**  val notTest:NotTest="abc";This one also implicitly transfer String to NotTest, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Francis, How about making a new sub-trait that extends TestBase.  Then all of the classes you want to be able to implicitly covert can extend that trait instead of TestBase directly, and you can use Jasper-M's solution.

Comment: If `NotTest` is not a subclass of `TestBase`, then `val notTest:NotTest="abc"` will not compile with the solution I provided.

Comment: @Jasper-M, I tried, and actually **[A <: TestBase]** doesn't seem to work. val notTest:NotTest="abc" successfully convert.

Comment: You are right, I tried it and scala doesn't seem to give a rat's ass about the type bound. I am puzzled... Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @dhg, hey, glad you reply. you mean **trait SubTestBase extends TestBase**?, I tried, but **class NotTest(str:String)**; **val notTest:NotTest="abc"** still converts too.